# The platform does not support 'compiler.libraries.ldflags' for precompiled libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

A) My setup:

Xubuntu 20.04, ROS2 Foxy, microros foxy 2.05, Arduino Due, Jetson Nano 4GB

B) My question:

I just trying out microROS with my Arduino Due. However, this error come out when I try to just compile without uploading the code. Note that I already successfully build microros workspace according to this guide: https://micro.ros.org/docs/tutorials/core/first_application_linux/  Can anyone help?

```
The platform does not support 'compiler.libraries.ldflags' for precompiled libraries.
```

[image: image description]

C) What I have tried

- I already did the patch SAMD guide based on this https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino
- I already uninstall and install back Arduino IDE
- I already try basic blink code to upload to my Arduino Due and it works. So now the problem revolve around the microros library.
- I already setup microros workspace

D) Below is my platform.txt

The location: /home//arduino/arduino-1.8.19/hardware/arduino/avr

```
# Arduino SAM Core and platform.
# ------------------------------
#
# For more info:
# https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5-3rd-party-Hardware-specification

name=Arduino ARM (32-bits) Boards
version=1.6.12

# SAM3 compile variables
# ----------------------

compiler.warning_flags=-w
compiler.warning_flags.none=-w
compiler.warning_flags.default=
compiler.warning_flags.more=-Wall
compiler.warning_flags.all=-Wall -Wextra

compiler.path={runtime.tools.arm-none-eabi-gcc-4.8.3-2014q1.path}/bin/
compiler.c.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.c.flags=-c -g -Os {compiler.warning_flags} -std=gnu11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -Dprintf=iprintf -MMD
compiler.c.elf.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.c.elf.flags=-Os -Wl,--gc-sections
compiler.S.cmd=arm-none-eabi-gcc
compiler.S.flags=-c -g -x assembler-with-cpp -MMD
compiler.cpp.cmd=arm-none-eabi-g++
compiler.cpp.flags=-c -g -Os {compiler.warning_flags} -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostdlib -fno-threadsafe-statics --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -MMD
compiler.ar.cmd=arm-none-eabi-ar
compiler.ar.flags=rcs
compiler.objcopy.cmd=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
compiler.objcopy.eep.flags=-O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0
compiler.elf2hex.flags=-O binary
compiler.elf2hex.cmd=arm-none-eabi-objcopy
compiler.ldflags=
compiler.size.cmd=arm-none-eabi-size
compiler.define=-DARDUINO=
compiler.combine.flags=-u _sbrk -u link -u _close -u _fstat -u _isatty -u _lseek -u _read -u _write -u _exit -u kill -u _getpid

# This can be overridden in boards.txt
build.extra_flags=

# These can be overridden in platform.local.txt
compiler.c.extra_flags=
compiler.c.elf.extra_flags=
compiler.cpp.extra_flags=
compiler.S.extra_flags=
compiler.ar.extra_flags=
compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags=
compiler.libraries.ldflags=


compiler.libsam.c.flags="-I{build.system.path}/libsam" "-I{build.system.path}/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include/" "-I{build.system.path}/CMSIS/Device/ATMEL/"

# USB Flags
# ---------
build.usb_flags=-DUSB_VID={build.vid} -DUSB_PID={build.pid} -DUSBCON '-DUSB_MANUFACTURER={build.usb_manufacturer}' '-DUSB_PRODUCT={build.usb_product}'

# Default usb manufacturer will be replaced at compile time using
# numeric vendor ID if available or by board's specific value.
build.usb_manufacturer="Unknown"


# SAM3 compile patterns
# ---------------------

## Compile c files
recipe.c.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.cmd}" {compiler.c.flags} -mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.c.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {compiler.libsam.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

## Compile c++ files
recipe.cpp.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.cpp.cmd}" {compiler.cpp.flags} -mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.cpp.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {compiler.libsam.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

## Compile S files
recipe.S.o.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.S.cmd}" {compiler.S.flags} -mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb -DF_CPU={build.f_cpu} -DARDUINO={runtime.ide.version} -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch} {compiler.S.extra_flags} {build.extra_flags} {compiler.libsam.c.flags} {includes} "{source_file}" -o "{object_file}"

## Create archives
# archive_file_path is needed for backwards compatibility with IDE 1.6.5 or older, IDE 1.6.6 or newer overrides this value
archive_file_path={build.path}/{archive_file}
recipe.ar.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.ar.cmd}" {compiler.ar.flags} {compiler.ar.extra_flags} "{archive_file_path}" "{object_file}"

## Combine gc-sections, archives, and objects
recipe.c.combine.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.c.elf.cmd}" -mcpu={build.mcu} -mthumb {compiler.c.elf.flags} "-T{build.variant.path}/{build.ldscript}" "-Wl,-Map,{build.path}/{build.project_name}.map" {compiler.c.elf.extra_flags} -o "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf" "-L{build.path}" -Wl,--cref -Wl,--check-sections -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--entry=Reset_Handler -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=report-all -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align -Wl,--start-group {compiler.combine.flags} {object_files} {compiler.libraries.ldflags} "{build.variant.path}/{build.variant_system_lib}" "{build.path}/{archive_file}" -Wl,--end-group -lm -lgcc

## Create output (.bin file)
recipe.objcopy.bin.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.elf2hex.cmd}" {compiler.elf2hex.flags} {compiler.elf2hex.extra_flags} "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf" "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin"

## Save hex
recipe.output.tmp_file={build.project_name}.bin
recipe.output.save_file={build.project_name}.{build.variant}.bin

## Compute size
recipe.size.pattern="{compiler.path}{compiler.size.cmd}" -A "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.elf"
recipe.size.regex=\.text\s+([0-9]+).*


# SAM3 Uploader tools
# -------------------

# BOSSA
tools.bossac.path={runtime.tools.bossac.path}
tools.bossac.cmd=bossac
tools.bossac.cmd.windows=bossac.exe

tools.bossac.upload.params.verbose=-i -d
tools.bossac.upload.params.quiet=
tools.bossac.upload.params.verify=-v
tools.bossac.upload.pattern="{path}/{cmd}" {upload.verbose} --port={serial.port.file} -U {upload.native_usb} -e -w {upload.verify} -b "{build.path}/{build.project_name}.bin" -R

tools.bossac_remote.upload.pattern=/usr/bin/run-bossac {upload.verbose} --port=ttyATH0 -U {upload.native_usb} -e -w -v -b /tmp/sketch.bin -R
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/404335/the-platform-does-not-support-%27compiler.libraries.ldflags%27-for-precompiled-libraries./) by [dual-swordsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40035/dual-swordsman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2022-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please open an issue in the micro-ROS for Arduino Github repo so we can track it.

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2022-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dual-swordsman](https://answers.ros.org/users/40035/dual-swordsman/) on 2022-07-28**:
Hi I found out that there is a similar issue based on #819 issue https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/issues/819

I followed SpMakris guide and the error is gone. https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/issues/819

However, I came across error on gcc incompatibility due to gcc used in micro ros arduino is 2014 (outdate) and gcc in my jetson nano is the latest one. I will follow up in this issue https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/issues/315. I saw the guide by  Acuadros95 but I don't know how to do the "Set the local path of the desired compiler:" step.